# Checking if two substring overlaps in O(n) time

Tags: arrays, string, algorithm

If I have a string S of length n, and a list of tuples (a,b), where a  specifies the staring position of the substring of S and b is the length of the substring. To check if any substring overlaps, we can, for example, mark the position in S whenever it's touched. However, I think this will take O(n^2) time if the list of tuples has a size of n (looping the tuple list, then looping S).

Is it possible to check if any substring actually overlaps with the other in O(n) time?

Edit:
For example, S = "abcde". Tuples = [(1,2),(3,3),(4,2)], representing "ab","cde" and "de". I want to the know an overlap is discovered when (4,2) is read.

I was thinking it is O(n^2) because you get a tuple every time, then you need to loop through the substring in S to see if any character is marked dirty.

Edit 2:
I cannot exit once a collide is detected. Imagine I need to report all the subsequent tuples that collide, so i have to loop through the whole tuple list.

Edit 3:
A high level view of the algorithm:

```
 for each tuple (a,b)
   for (int i=a; i <= a+b; i++)
      if S[i] is dirty 
        then report tuple and break //break inner loop only
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. How could the time complexity depend on the length of the `String` but not on the length of the list of tuples?

Comment: @pbabcdefp I have edited the question and added why I think it is O(n^2)

Comment: What does overlap mean? The overlap is related to the tuples, or related to S? Could you give more examples?

Comment: @coderz overlap means if two substring of S share at least 1 position. (3,3) overlaps with (4,2) because they "de" (S[4] and S[5], S starts with 1) .

Comment: Do you need to report every collision (for example, `(0, 2)` collides with `(1, 1)`, `(1, 1)` collides with `(1, 2)`, and `(0, 2)` collides with `(1, 2)`), or do you just need to report every tuple that has a collision? If you need to report every collision, there may be more than `O(n)` of them, and it can take longer than `O(n)` just to output everything.

Comment: Also, if `(0, 2)` collides with `(1, 2)`, do you need to report both tuples, or just one of them?

Comment: as @pbabcdefp pointed out, I think your complexity analysis need to include the length of the tuple list, say `t` as well as `n`. The complexity of the process is more like `O(n*t)` to me. e.g. [ (n,1), (n-1,1), ...(1,1)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic approach is correct, but you could optimize your stopping condition, in a way that guarantees bounded complexity in the worst case. Think about it this way - how many positions in S would you have to traverse and mark in the worst case?

If there is no collision, then at worst you'll visit length(S) positions (and run out of tuples by then, since any additional tuple would have to collide). If there is a collision - you can stop at the first marked object, so again you're bounded by the max number of unmarked elements, which is length(S)

EDIT: since you added a requirement to report **all** colliding tuples, let's calculate this again (extending my comment) -

Once you marked all elements, you can detect collision for every further tuple with a single step (O(1)), and therefore you would need O(n+n) = O(n).
This time, each step would either mark an unmarked element (overall n in the worst case), or identify a colliding tuple (worst O(tuples) which we assume is also n).

The actual steps may be interleaved, since the tuples may be organized in any way without colliding first, but once they do (after at most n tuples which cover all n elements before colliding for the first time), you have to collide every time on the first step. other arrangements may collide earlier even before marking all elements, but again - you're just rearranging the same number of steps.

Worst case example: one tuple covering the entire array, then n-1 tuples (doesn't matter which) - 
 [(1,n), (n,1), (n-1,1), ...(1,1)]

First tuple would take n steps to mark all elements, the rest would take O(1) each to finish. overall O(2n)=O(n). Now convince yourself that the following example takes the same number of steps -

[(1,n/2-1), (1,1), (2,1), (3,1), (n/2,n/2), (4,1), (5,1) ...(n,1)]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To and were your first question, should;t it be length of S? For e.g., the first tuple cover the whole S, then all the following will collide. So the first outer loop run n times, then the following runs O(1) time.....is this correct?

Comment: @xcoder, if the outer loop iterates over the tuples, then it would run once (on the first tuple), have the inner loop mark all n elements as touched, and then immediately exit on the first check of the second tuple since it would collide.

Comment: Perhaps I should make this clearer. I cannot exit once a collide is detected. Imagine I need to report all the subsequent tuples that collide, so i have to loop through  the whole tuple list.

Comment: This is adding a new constraint, but it does not break the complexity. Once you marked all elements, you can detect collision for every further tuple with a single check (O(1)), and therefore you would need O(n+n) = O(n) - each check would either  mark an unmarked element (overall n in the worst case), or identify a colliding tuple (worst O(tuples) which we assume is also n).

Comment: Oh! it starts making sense! It is not O(n^2) because for the check, I do not need to go through the whole list every time!  I am just interested, will it change anything if say, the tuple list is like [(n,1),(n-1,1),...(1,1)]?

Comment: @xcoder - That's the nice part - it doesn't matter. Each step will either mark an element (once and for good), or detect a collision and proceed to the next tuple. In this last example, you'll just do O(n) marking steps and see there's no collision. A more interesting example (maybe that's what you meant?) is if that list was: [(1,n), (n,1), (n-1,1), ...(1,1)] - the first element would iterate over the entire array once, the rest would take 1 step each.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description and comment, the overlap problem may be not about string algorithm, it can be regarded as "segment overlap" problem.

Just use your example, it can be translated to 3 segments: [1, 2], [3, 5], [4, 5]. The question is to check whether the 3 segments have overlap.

Suppose we have `m` segments each have format [start, end] which means segment start position and end position, one efficient algorithm to detect overlap is to sort them by start position in ascending order, it takes `O(m * lgm)`. Then iterate the sorted `m` segments, for each segment, try to find whether its end position, here you only need to check:

```
if(start[i] <= max(end[j], 1 <= j <= i-1) {
    segment i is overlap;
}
maxEnd[i] = max(maxEnd[i-1], end[i]); // update max end position of 1 to i
```

Which each check operation takes `O(1)`. Then the total time complexity is `O(m*lgm + m)`, which can be regarded as `O(m*lgm)`. While for each output, time complexity is related to each tuple's length, which is also related to `n`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a segment overlap problem and the solution should be possible in `O(n)` itself if the list of tuples has been sorted in ascending order wrt the first field. Consider the following approach:

1. Transform the intervals from (start, number of characters) to (start, inclusive_end). Hence the above example becomes: `[(1,2),(3,3),(4,2)] ==> [(1, 2), (3, 5), (4, 5)]`
2. The tuples are valid if transformed consecutive tuples `(a, b)` and `(c, d)` always follow `b < c`. Else there is an overlap in the tuples mentioned above.

Each of `1` and `2` can be done in `O(n)` if the array is sorted in the form mentioned above.